# Javascript progress bar button that increments value by 1 and changes style width by 10

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

```js
function getProgress() {
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("style","width");
 return document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML;
 }

function setProgress(value) {
 document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("aria-valuenow",value);
 document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("style","width " +value+ "%"); 
 document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML = (value+ "%"); 
}

function increment() {
 var i = getProgress();
 if(i < 100){
  i++;
  setProgress(i); 
 }else{
  alert("Download Finished");
 }
}

function decrement() {
 var d = getProgress();
 setProgress(d - 1);
}

function resetButton() {
 var r = getProgress();
 setProgress(r = 0);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
  
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
 
  </head>
  <body>
 <!-- Container -->
 <div class="container">
 
    <h1>This Process bar is animated using <br>JavaScript!</h1>
 <br>
 
 <!-- Div For Progress Bar -->
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar"  style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="progressbar" >0%</div>
 </div>
 
 <br>
 <!-- Buttons -->
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick = "increment()">Increment</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="resetButton()">Reset</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="decrement()">Decrement</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="">Start Auto Progress!</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="">Stop Auto Progress!</button>
 
 <p id="value"> </p>
 <!-- End of Container -->
 </div>
 
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get the increment button to change the values by 1 each time it's clicked, but I also want the width style to increase by 10 each time. I was wondering if anyone could help me please. Thanks.

Here below is the Javascript Part

```
function getProgress() {
    return document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
    document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("style","width");
    document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML;
}

function setProgress(value) {
    document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("aria-valuenow",value);
    document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("style","width " +value+ "%");  
    document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML = (value+ "%"); 
}

function increment() {
    var i = getProgress();
    if(i < 100) {
        i++;
        setProgress(i); 
    } else {
        alert("Download Finished");
    }
}

function decrement() {
    var d = getProgress();
    setProgress(d - 1);
}

function resetButton() {
    var r = getProgress();
    setProgress(r = 0);
}
```

And here is the HTML part of the project..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 

shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">


        <title>Progress Bar</title>

  </head>
  <body>
<!-- Container -->
    <div class="container">

    <h1>This Process bar is animated using <br>JavaScript!</h1>
    <br>

    <!-- Div For Progress Bar -->
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar"  style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="progressbar" >0%</div>
    </div>

    <br>
<!-- Buttons -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick = "increment()">Increment</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="resetButton()">Reset</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="decrement()">Decrement</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="">Start Auto Progress!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="">Stop Auto Progress!</button>
    <p id="value"> </p>
    <!-- End of Container -->
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>here
```

can provide more details if needed thanks

Comment: I think you forgot the code!

Comment: @jakemingolla yes sorry haha refresh =]

Comment: You are returning the function before executing `document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("style","width");
    document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML;}`

Comment: what could i use?

Comment: Could you post your HTML and Javascript as a runnable code snippet? That would make it easier for someone to debug.

Comment: @tremor ok sure

Comment: @Fact thank you, I've added an answer that you should find suitable. If so please mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

There were issues in your functions for getProgress and setProgress.  In getProgress, you were returning 3 times, which isn't how return works, in this case we'll get the value and return just the value.  And in setProgress your setAttribute for style/width was syntactically incorrect. A working version is now below.

```js
function getProgress() {
  var d = document.getElementById("progressbar").getAttribute("aria-valuenow");
  return d;
}

function setProgress(value) {
  document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("aria-valuenow", value);  
  document.getElementById("progressbar").setAttribute("style", "width: " + value + "%;");
  document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML = (value + "%");
}

function increment() {
  var i = getProgress();
  if (i < 100) {
    i++;
    setProgress(i);
  } else {
    alert("Download Finished");
  }
}

function decrement() {
  var d = getProgress();
  setProgress(d - 1);
}

function resetButton() {
  var r = getProgress();
  setProgress(r = 0);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Progress Bar</title>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Container -->
  <div class="container">

    <h1>This Process bar is animated using <br>JavaScript!</h1>
    <br>

    <!-- Div For Progress Bar -->
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="progressbar">0%</div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <!-- Buttons -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="resetButton()">Reset</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="decrement()">Decrement</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="">Start Auto Progress!</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="">Stop Auto Progress!</button>

    <p id="value"> </p>
    <!-- End of Container -->
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```